# How is it Done - Scaling of Tweet-Button Counter

Tags: css, button, twitter

I wonder how to (CSS-wise) realize a Button with a counter element like the Tweet-Button. The call-out seems to grow with the number of digits; the backgrund sprite used http://platform0.twitter.com/widgets/images/tweet.png has a significantly wider call-out than visible in the basic (i.e. one digit) button rendered.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use a correct background position.
They use two elements:

```
<span><a href=#" >1</a></span>
```

Apply a background to the span, position it (according to the position of the image in the sprite), and specify the padding for positioning the number:

```
span {
    background-img: url("sprite.png");
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

This is the left side of the call-out. The '0 -50px' means the portion of the sprite 50px from the top, 0px from the left is used.

Next style the anchor and the trick is to apply the background to the right side of the element this time:

```
a {
    background-img: url("sprite.png");
    background-position: right -50px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

This background is aligned to the right side of the (growing) anchor and the left side is chopped of.
This way there are actually two images on top of each other, the right-side is on top of the left side (but they are really the same portion of the sprite). The number can grow only as much as the width of the original sprite, otherwise the left side of the anchor background (on top) will be visible.